# Dropdown inside a kendo grid in React

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

What I am trying to accomplish is to have a Dropdown inside a grid in the best way possible. From what I see in Angular they can do it in templates. In react, this is available, but impossible to use any kind of components.

> Templates are only supported in the form of "strings". Templates in the form of React components are not supported.

What is the better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest version of the Kendo react Grid, based on this demo https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/editing/editing/

Here is how to apply custom cell:

```
<GridColumn cell={this.CommandCell} />
...
class DropDownCell extends GridCell {
//...
handleChange(e) {
    this.props.onChange({
        dataItem: this.props.dataItem,
        field: this.props.field,
        syntheticEvent: e.syntheticEvent,
        value: e.target.value
    });
}
//...
render() {
    const value = this.props.dataItem[this.props.field];

    if (this.props.dataItem.inEdit) {
    return (
        <td>
            <DropDownList
                //...
            />
        </td>
    );
}
```

See the full runable version here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-grid-dropdown-editor